# Does tcsetpgrp() succeds when the caller belong to a background process?

Tags: c, signals, posix

According to the [POSIX specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/tcsetpgrp.html), `tcsetpgrp` can cause `SIGTTOU` to be sent to the group of the calling process if it is a background process.

However I can't understand if in such case the foreground group is changed.

Also, if the foreground group is actually changed despite the signal generation, I wonder what happens to the session and to the terminal if the new foreground group is the one that is going to receive the `SIGTTOU`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL:DR:**

No the foreground group does not change. This makes sense since the signal is supposed to be sent when the process is changing a setting on the terminal -- an output operation. The signal would also not be delivered to the process (now the foreground group) if the change succeeded, because then it could get stuck without someone to send SIGCONT.

**Longer answer:**

A simple example:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <signal.h>


void sig(int signo) {
    const char* msg = strsignal(signo); // XXX: Not async-signal-safe.
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, msg, strlen(msg));
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, "\n", 1);
}

int main() {
    char cntl_tty[L_ctermid];
    ctermid(cntl_tty);

    signal(SIGTTOU, sig);
    signal(SIGCONT, sig);

    int fd = open(cntl_tty, O_RDONLY);
    if (fd == -1) {
        perror("open");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (tcsetpgrp(fd, getpgrp()) == -1) {
        perror("tcsetpgrp");
    } else {
        puts("foregrounded");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When this code is started as a background process and `SIGTTOU` is handled, this loops forever printing that the signal is received. The `perror` is never called, which implies that the kernel restarts the system call. Sending `SIGCONT` does not matter. The foregrounding never succeeds. However when foregrounding the code through the shell, "foregrounded" is printed as expected.

When the signal disposition for `SIGTTOU` is changed to `SIG_IGN`, "foregrounded" is printed immediately.

Comment: Thanks, clear and nice answer... However I wonder if the perror is not reached just because of the print int the signal handler: after all printing from a background process should produce SIGTTOU, which would cause the handler to restart, printing again, causing a new SITTOU... in an infinite loop.

Comment: Good point, I hadn't thought of that. I tried it again, removing the prints, leaving an empty signal handler body, and the behavior remains the same. It is kind of odd that the print occurred at all, since it should've failed with I suppose EINTR.

Comment: D'oh, that's the shell writing "Stopped (tty output)", nevermind. =)